# Initializing an object reference from astatic analyzer

Tags: java, java-threads

To publish an object safely, both the reference to the object and the object's state must be made visible to other threads at the same time. A properly constructed object can be safely published by:

- Initializing an object reference from a static initializer
- Storing a reference to it into a volatile field or AtomicReference
- Storing a reference to it into a final field of a properly constructed object
- Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a
  lock.

My doubt here is how will initializing an object from  a static initializer work. I believe this implied using a singleton pattern

Comment: The static initializer works because it's part of the initialization of the class object.  When the JVM loads a class from disc, it does so asynchronously and has to make its own writes visible.  Thus, you basically get a free ride on the JVM's thread safety.

Comment: The lazy initialization of static fields using the "Lazy Static Holder Class Pattern" (Essential Java, 2nd Ed.) takes advantage of the thread safety (and automatic safe publication) built into the JVM during class initialization as mentioned above.